# node.js sign in to website and get contents of new page

Tags: node.js, http, http-redirect

There are many questions about this already but they are all very generalized. I am relatively new to http requests so I would like the answer to a very specific example.

I just created a wordpress (.com) account:

Username: example28574

Password: password28574

I want to log in to wordpress.com and get the contents of the page it redirects me to, using node.js, with the username and password above.

login page: https://wordpress.com/log-in
The page I want to get the contents of: https://wordpress.com/

Clarification:
This doesn't have anything to do with WordPress, it's just the example website

Edit: What I have tried so far

```
var request = require('request');
var request = request.defaults({jar: true});

var loginPage = "https://login.wordpress.org/wp-login.php";
request.post(
    loginPage,
    {"log": "example28574", "pwd": "password28574", "wp-submit": "Log In", "redirect_to": "https://login.wordpress.org/"},
    function (error, response, body) {
        console.log(1);
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body);
        }
        if(error) console.log(error);
        if(response.statusCode != 200) console.log(response.statusCode);
    }
);
```

This prints the login page.

Comment: There are **tons** of tutorials on how to scrap web pages using node.js. Please try to follow some and then come back with specific questions.

Comment: Oops, sorry. I forgot to put my code

Comment: @Wiktor Zychla can you point me to one of these tutorials? I know how to scrape web pages, but not how to sign in to one and then scrape.

Comment: Have you tried automating a browser using puppeteer? That should be way easier.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how you want to make it work. Will your code work like real-browser or will you only need http response?

If you want it to act like a real browser, then you can use something like Puppeteer. Otherwise, if only thing you need is data, http responses, then you can trace webpage requests and find out which endpoints it makes request to, then you can do the same with basic http requests.

Comment: An example using puppeteer would be nice. I'm new to this, I have no clue what endpoints are and how to trace them.

Comment: You can basically use browser's inspector, network tab, to list all http requests on page

Comment: I did that. I found the request I was looking for. On the bottom, it says "form-data". I copied all that form data into my code, but it still does not work